# Override @Where clause condition in Hibernate 4.3.4

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a sample code piece like this-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Where(clause = "active IS TRUE")
public class Employee{
}
```

This will fetch all the record of *employee* table having *active=true or 1*. In some cases, it may require that I want to load the records having *active=false or 0*.

If I write my code as `FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.active IS FALSE` but the generated query contains bot the conditions given in HQL and Annotations.

Hence, the expected results is not coming. Is there anyway to override this predefined `@Where` defined over entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't override it inside your class because if you take a look at the **[@Where documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html)** you will see that this interface is annotated `@Retention(value=RUNTIME)` so it has `RUNTIME` as a `RetentionPolicy` and you can see in the **[RetentionPolicy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)** that:

> **RUNTIME:** 
>   Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.

Which force the `@Where` annotation to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so it will be applied all over this class.

Comment: So, is there no any other way to achieve this task, so that I don't need to change each of my query?

Comment: The simplest way is to avoid specifying `@Where` for the whole class.

Answer (score 9):

I know its too old question but I was facing same issue and thought I should share my workaround.

Totally agree with @cнŝdk answer as you cannot override but you can ignore `@Where` clause by defining `nativeQuery` as below:

`@Query(value = "Select * from customer where company_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true) List<Customer> findByCompanyIdIgnoringEntityWhere(Long companyId);`

The SQL in the @Query annotation must point the table's name and the fields' names (not entity's name).